# FluentValidation: Comparing a value with an aggregate of values?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I find FluentValidation straightforward when making simple rules for properties on a single class, but as soon as I need to compare values from collections (e.g. a `List<T>` property), it gets super-hairy. Assume the follwing two minimal classes:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public PurchaseOrder()
    {
        LineItems = new List<LineItem>();
    }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

And this class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PurchaseOrder order = new PurchaseOrder();
        order.LineItems.Add(new LineItem() { Price = 12m });
        order.LineItems.Add(new LineItem() { Price = 14m });
        order.Total = 26m;

        PurchaseOrderValidator validator = new PurchaseOrderValidator();
        ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(order);
    }
}
```

How would `PurchaseOrderValidator` look like to make sure that the sum of all `LineItem.Price` equals the `PurchaseOrder.Total`? Here's a stub (although I'm not sure `Must()` is the way to go):

```
public class PurchaseOrderValidator : AbstractValidator<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Total).Must(MatchSumOfLineItems);
    }

    private bool MatchSumOfLineItems(decimal arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with validating, but why don't you just return the sum of `LineItem` prices in the `get` of `Total` property and make `set` private

Comment: It's a legacy application, and for now, my task is to validate the outputs, not make changes to the application.

Comment: What have you tried. post code of your attempt at the validator

Comment: Added a stub for `PurchaseOrderValidator` that always succeeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `.Equal()`

```
public class PurchaseOrderValidator : AbstractValidator<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Total).Equal(x => x.LineItems.Sum(item => item.Price));
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. This was just the kind of one-liner I hoped for.

Answer (score 5):

Just create validation method that takes `PurchaseOrder` as input and do whatever you want with it

```
public class PurchaseOrderValidator : AbstractValidator<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(MatchSumOfLineItems);
    }

    private bool MatchSumOfLineItems(PurchaseOrder arg)
    {
        return arg.Total == arg.LineItems.Sum(i => i.Price);
    }
}
```

or if you want to add validation specifically for `Total` property you can use another `Must` overload accepts `Func<decimal, PurchaseOrder, bool>`

```
public class PurchaseOrderValidator : AbstractValidator<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public PurchaseOrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Total).Must(MatchSumOfLineItems);
    }

    private bool MatchSumOfLineItems(PurchaseOrder order, decimal sum)
    {
        return sum == order.LineItems.Sum(i => i.Price);
    }
}
```